# for loop gets executed just once

Tags: php

I have created an array dynamically like this way

```
$names = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $names[] = $i;
}
```

then created part

```
 $parts = count($names) / 20;
```

and created a sub array  then loop through the parts

```
$j = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $parts; $i++) {
    echo "Part" . $i."<br>";
    $newarray = array_slice($names, $j, 20);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($newarray); $i++) {
        echo $i;
    }
    $j = $j + 20;
}
```

The problem is that this code displays from zero to 19 It doesn't display the other parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the inner and outer loops use the same control variable `$i`, so just change the inner one...

```
$j = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $parts; $i++) {
    echo "Part" . $i."<br>";
    $newarray = array_slice($names, $j, 20);
    for ($i1 = 0; $i1 < count($newarray); $i1++) {
        echo $i1;
    }
    $j = $j + 20;
}
```

Comment: Could you please use a better variable name?